# RDF/XML to XHTML/HTML5 for Semantic web

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, semantic-markup, rdfa

So, I have numerous files in RDF/XML format which I want to use on the web.  I want to be part of the Linked Data community and have HTML and RDF versions of my data files.  Usually, what I've found is information about going the other way.  However, if one had RDF data and wanted to share it, in a format that could be read by people on a web page, what would be the best way to do this?

1) I found a nice tool at: foaf-visualizer.org, which uses JQuery and CSS to present foaf files.  It is a rather nice tool but I didn't see that the code itself was available so that one could extend it for other tags besides the ones that the author chose to display.  Maybe, I should create my own JQuery solution.  I took an RDF file and converted it online to RDFa and could then use that, or the RDF file to display content from the RDF/XML file.

2) Use some form of style sheet transformation to convert either the rdf or the rdfa into an HTML version of the file.  This second option would require manually inserting text into the document.  The tool that created RDFa from RDF/XML just created a bunch of div tags using XSLT.  Nothing that would display in the browser.

3) Some other version or approach to this might be possible.
Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option (but not necessarily the simplest) would be to load all the RDF/XML files into a triple store, and use a front-end such as [Pubby](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/pubby/) or [Linked Data Pages](http://csarven.ca/how-to-create-a-linked-data-site) to generate the published HTML and RDF versions.

Comment: With all the reading and research I've done on this, and some extensive work, I am embarrassed to say that I thought that an RDF/XML file, was a triple store as the RDF is data, as well as being able to store schema, meta data.  In my reading of Semantic Web Programming and Programming the Semantic Web, they  use the rdf file to query and as the data source.  So, could you explain what is meant by or how one loads RDF files into a triple store?  Would this be something i'd setup on my own server or would I submit it elsewhere, like freebase.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem you describe over and over again and - apart from the solution suggested by Richard - I am sorry to say that there is no definitive solution.

However, I found at least two tools that could be of help:

- [**Rhizomic ReDeFer**](http://rhizomik.net/html/redefer/): even if conceived for a very different purpose, its RDF2HTML+RDFa service could be used to convert an RDF file to an HTML page with also RDFa embedded
- [**Parrot**](http://ontorule-project.eu/parrot/parrot): on the contrary, this tool was explicitly designed for documenting RDF and OWL files; however, last time I tried to use it I got some problems with the Javascript

Personally I prefer the former and used it extensively, but in perspective the latter is more promising for your purpose. The interesting thing is that both of them produce the HTML page with RDFa annotations.